# Melt creature parts?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently killed a Hill Titan made entirely from *gold* in my Dwarf Fortress game, and I fully intended to melt the gold, make memorial stones, and engrave the tale of its defeat on its remains.  However the *melt* option does not appear on `Thalu Ireneaye's gold`.

Is there a way I can melt it, or otherwise make use of that lovely pile of titan gold outside my entrance?

[image: Thalu Ireneaye's gold]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the current version of dwarf fortress (version 31.25), there is no way to do anything with inorganic Titan / Forgotten Beast remains.